# Mysql - user variables and order by rand within concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which is intended to return the number of war casualties on the current day during the World War One era (exact year is picked at random).  However, the below query only works if I set the rYear variable in a separate query, and merely refer to it in this one.  Day and month work fine.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT Deaths FROM new_schema.totals WHERE Date = concat
(@rYear := WarYear FROM new_schema.`WW1-years` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1,'-',
@MonthNum := MONTH(curdate()),'-',
@DateNum := DAYOFMONTH(curdate()));
```

Comment: Maybe I'm guessing wrong, but shouldn't this be `@rYear := SELECT WarYear FROM new_schema.`WW1-years` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I added the select and removed the hyphen from the WW1-years so I could take out the backticks, but now workbench reports 2 errors instead of the original 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is simply not the correct syntax. Try this:

```
SELECT Deaths FROM new_schema.totals WHERE Date = CONCAT(
    (SELECT @rYear := WarYear FROM new_schema.WW1-years ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
    '-',
    @MonthNum := MONTH(curdate()),
    '-',
    @DateNum := DAYOFMONTH(curdate())
);
```

As a side note, since WW1 is over (obviously) you could simply use `floor(1914 + rand() * 5)` instead of a table ordered by rand.

Comment: Great, thankyou.  As you may have realised, I'm rather a novice at SQL.

Comment: @flowerpowered Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.